# Отображение вводимых символов в виде *

Tags: winforms, visual-c++

Доброго времени суток. Не могли бы вы подсказать, можно ли сделать так, что бы символы, которые я ввожу в textBox в запущенной программе, показывались в виде "`*`" (звёздочек)?

Answer (score 5):

Решения типовых проблем, возникающих при работе с технологиями программирования от Microsoft разумно искать в базе знаний MSDN.

[How to: Create a Password Text Box with the Windows Forms TextBox Control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d3223ht2.aspx)

Фрагмент кода из статьи по приведенной ссылке:

```
private:
   void InitializeMyControl()
   {
      // Set to no text.
      textBox1->Text = "";
      // The password character is an asterisk.
      textBox1->PasswordChar = '*';
      // The control will allow no more than 14 characters.
      textBox1->MaxLength = 14;
   }
```